# AngularJS Component binding is undefined on minified

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, binding, components

I have problem with my app. When I am building it with `grunt serve`, everything is working fine, but when I try to build it to dist, it's seems that my component's binding is failing somehow. The code looks something like this:

```
angular.module('jsonParserApp')
.component('leafTemplate', {
  templateUrl: 'views/itemList.html',
  bindings: {
    readonly: '<',
    //other bindings (works properly)
  },
  controller: ['$scope', 'copiedValue', function($scope, copiedValue) {
    //code
    this.$onChanges = function(changesObj) {
      console.log('onChanges', changesObj);
    //code
    };
    //code
  }]
});
```

And then when I check what are value of 
    `ctrl.readonly` 
in `console.log` it returns

```
{
  "readonly": {
    "currentValue": true,
    "previousValue": UNINITIALIZED_VALUE
  } 
}
```

however when I look at logged value on `grunt`'s dist it returns

```
{
  "readonly": {
    "currentValue": undefined,
    "previousValue": UNINITIALIZED_VALUE
  } 
}
```

What is important to mention is that this components are built recursively. That code in html looks more or less like this: (first sample of code is initialize value readonly to true or false, and then it should be propagated to child elements)

```
<ul ng-show="main.toggleInputTree" class="overflow-auto" flex>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in main.inputJson">
    <leaf-template k="key" t="main.inputJson" i="{{$index}}" readonly="true" parent="$"></leaf-template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(second sample of code which should be propagated from it's parent - on `grunt serve` its working, on `grunt`'s dist - not)

```
<ul ng-show="ctrl.displayChildren" ng-if="!ctrl.isString(ctrl.t, ctrl.k)">
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in ctrl.t[ctrl.k]">
    <leaf-template k="key" t="ctrl.t[ctrl.k]" i="{{$index}}" readonly="ctrl.readonly" parent="{{ctrl.parent + '.' + ctrl.k}}"></leaf-template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What is the problem, why the value is not propagated on minified/uglified version?

**@UPDATE**

I tried to debug it and I found out something very interesting. Before building, html looks like this:

```
<leaf-template k="key" t="ctrl.t[ctrl.k]" i="{{$index}}" readonly="ctrl.readonly" parent="{{ctrl.parent + '.' + ctrl.k}}"></leaf-template>
```

and within dist version, $templateCache hold html which looks like this

```
<leaf-template k="key" t="main.inputJson" i="{{$index}}" readonly parent="$"></leaf-template>
```

For some reasons, `readonly="ctrl.readonly"` is cut to `readonly`

Comment: If you solved the problem, it is best to answer your the question. That way others will know the problem is solved. Also you can give yourself points by accepting the answer.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for advice. :)

Answer (score 2):

Change name from `readonly` to anything else helped... Actually `readonly` is HTML input's attribute so uglify parsed `readonly="ctrl.readonly"` to just `readonly`.

Comment: Dude this really helped me :D